# Removing array from memory in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a 2d array consume 0 memory after I am done using it.
I want to implement something likes this:-

```
int a[][] = new int[10][10] // alloting new memory say 400Mb

// do something

// Now I want to make it null

a => null // clearing the 400 Mb it took before

// do something
```

Comment: This is what garbage collection is for.

Comment: I search about garbage collecter as well, but as far as I understand, it clears variables pointing to null. so how do I point the 2d array to null ?

Comment: You're confusing variables and objects. Read the duplicate question and the detailed answers

Comment: Usually, the best thing to do is to use variables on local scope, not a class scope

Comment: When your variable loses it's reference, the garbage collector will reclaim it and free it from memory automatically, setting it to null might help that, but when it'll be reclaimed is will depende on the JVM, usually you don't have to worry about that.